# Creating a Struct then passing a vector with those struct by reference

Tags: c++

I would like to start off by saying there are many questions like this asked but for me it is quit hard to understand the explanations unless it deals with my situation.

HERE: is the Full Questions for the program I am working on.

11.7: Customer Accounts
Write a program  that uses a structure to store  the following data about a customer account:

```
 Customer name 
 Customer address
 City
 State
 ZIP code
 Telephone
 Account balance
 Date of last payment
```

The program  should use an array  of at least 20 structures. It should let the user enter data into the array , change the contents of any element , and display all the data stored  in the array . The program  should have a menu-driven user interface.

Here is some example code because pasting my full code was too much b/c I had to go through and add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct CustomerAccount{
        string customerName;
        string customerAddress;
        string customerCity;
        string customerState;
        int customerZipCode;
        string customerTelephone;
        double customerAccountBalance;
        string customerDateOfLastPayment;
};

void testFunction(vector<CustomerAccount> &stuff){
    stuff.push_back(CustomerAccount());
    stuff[0].customerName = "dale";
    stuff[0].customerAddress = "123 test road";
    stuff[0].customerCity = "Fake City";
    stuff[0].customerState = "`Merica";
    stuff[0].customerZipCode = 12345;
    stuff[0].customerTelephone = "123-456-7899";
    stuff[0].customerAccountBalance = 200.20;
    stuff[0].customerDateOfLastPayment = "11/5/2016";
};



int main(){
    vector<CustomerAccount> stuff;
    //testFunction(vector<CustomerAccount> &stuff); ---Incorrect way (Thank you mkmostafa)
    testFunction(stuff); //The Correct way
    cout << stuff[0].customerName << endl;

};
```

Basically

1: Create a Vector.

2: Each element in that vector has the Structure and the associated data.

3: Modify the data in those elements by using functions, thus I need to pass the vector by reference.

***Side Notes***

I would love to have the program take in the customers name and then have the vector element be called that.

An example would be instead of stuff[0].customerZipCode, it could be stuff[Janet].customerZipCode  and I either be able to edit it or see the information. I have not a clue how to do that but that is just a side note that would be cool to know how to do.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct CustomerAccount{
        string customerName;
        string customerAddress;
        string customerCity;
        string customerState;
        int customerZipCode;
        string customerTelephone;
        double customerAccountBalance;
        string customerDateOfLastPayment;
};

void newCustomerAccount(vector<CustomerAccount> &custAcct){
    string newCustomerName, newCustomerAddress, newCustomerCity, newCustomerState, newCustomerTelephone, newCustomerDateOfLastPayment;
    int newCustomerZipCode;
    custAcct.push_back(CustomerAccount());
    double newCustomerAccountBalance;
    int id = custAcct.size();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Customer Name: ";
    cin >> newCustomerName;
    custAcct.customerName = newCustomerName;
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << endl;


};


void customerMenu(vector<CustomerAccount> &custAcct){
    int customerChoice;

    cout << "=======MENU=======" << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter new account information" << endl;
    cout << "2. Change account information" << endl;
    cout << "3. Display all account information" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit the program " << endl;
    cout << "Make a selection" << endl;
    cin >> customerChoice;

    switch(customerChoice){
    case(1):
        //"Enter new account information
        cout << "You have chosen to Enter new account information" << endl;
        newCustomerAccount(custAcct);

        break;
    case(2):
        //Change account information
        cout << "You have chosen to Change account information" << endl;

        break;
    case(3):
        //Display all account information
        cout << "You have chosen to display all account information" <<   endl;

        break;
    case(4):
        //Exit the program
        cout << "You have chosen to Exit the program" << endl;
        cout << "Bye!" << endl;
        cout << "The Size of the Array is: " << custAcct.size() << endl;
        break; 
    default:
        cout << "You did not make a valid selection" << endl;
        customerMenu(custAcct);
        break;
    };

};



int main()
{
    vector<CustomerAccount> custAcct;
    customerMenu(custAcct);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The example program is there so someone who knows how to do this can help me.

Comment: It won't compile, you are not calling `testFunction` correctly. It should be `testFunction(stuff);`

Comment: `testFunction(vector<CustomerAccount> &stuff);`  is a redeclaration of testFunction.

Comment: Your testFunction(vector<CustomerAccount> &), does a push_back of a default CustomerAccount instance, fine. However, the rest of the function assumes that the instance went into stuff[0], which would be true only when the the vector is empty.  Your testFunction stomps on the value at element 0, regardless of where the default instance was pushed.

Comment: how would you recommend fixing that because that is the issue I am having now? @DOUGLASO.MOEN

Comment: I am getting customer information and this could be the 1st or the 20th customer so I want to access the correct spot. I tried doing "stuff[stuff.size()-1].customerName" but my program ends at that point. I want if this to be customer 19, it gets the size of the array as 19 and the (19-1) is to put it into the 18th element b/c 0 element is the first.

Comment: Lots of ways to control it.  At present, I would probably (in testFunction) ... a) new an instance, b) fill in the instance, then c) push_back the instance.  Thus your testFunction need not know how full the vector is, or which element you are currently appending.

Comment: Part of C++ is thinking object oriented.  Perhaps you might consider refactoring testFunction() to be a member of the class it is initializing.  So the main() would invoke "customerAccount.testFunction()", where customerAccount is a 'temporary' local instance of that class.  Next it might be worth while to learn how to instantiate, initialize, and push_back all on one line of code.  Such fun.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the information @DOUGLASO.MOEN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already declaring testFunction to take the vector by reference. You need only to change the call in main to

```
testFunction(stuff);
```

For your side note you can use a map not a vector.

```
#include <map>
int main(){
  std::map<std::string, Customer> m;

  m["Janet"].name = "Janet"
  // set the rest

}
```

Comment: Does that actually pass by reference? if so could you explain to me how it does not (not being a smart ass, i am asking so I will know in the future). My understanding is you need to use the "&" to pass anything by reference, are vectors a special case?

Comment: void func(vector<int>); // passes by copy  ;;  
 

void func(vector<int>&);  // passes by reference.

Comment: Thank you for the "Side note" help.

Comment: How would I create something to keep track of the elements? stuff[0] then the next would be stuff[1].

Comment: why do u want to do exactly?

Comment: Basically I want to access the correct spot on the vector for the customer. If it is customer 1 I was to access the 0th element and 20 -> the 19th. The way I am doing it now is not working and Ill post a clip at the bottom of the question of my code.

Comment: if its just to set the values u don't need this. simply when you call the operator [ ] in the map, the default constructor will be called and creates a new object at the specified key name that u used (in this example it was Janet), then you can start filling out that object. check the edited code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. @mkmostafa